# Evaluate the integral: $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin ^{-1} \sqrt{x}}{x^2-x+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\sin ^{-1} \sqrt{x}}{x^2-x+1}
$$

What I have done is to substitute

$$
x=\sin ^2 \theta
$$
After that:

$$
d x=2 \sin \theta \cos \theta d \theta
$$

$$
\int \frac{2 \cdot \theta \cdot \sin \theta \cdot \cos \theta}{\sin ^4 \theta-\sin ^2 \theta+1} d\theta
$$

But I think that the process is bit lengthy.

Is there any other way to integrate the expression or proceed with the above integral ?

Thanks in advance.